# How can i get the length of a responsable URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loops, xmlhttprequest

I need the length of the `JSONOBJECT.routingpath.coordinates.length`
i am getting the response with this url.

http://193.70.60.44:3000/taxi_server/api/v1.0/taxiroute

response from server ...

```
[{
    "idtaxiroute": "3",
    "routingpath": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [49.9670749, 7.8994591],
            [49.9682897, 7.898872900000001],
            [49.9682897, 7.898872900000001],
            [49.9680662, 7.897596899999999],
            [49.9680662, 7.897596899999999],
            [49.9689168, 7.897404499999999],
            [49.9689168, 7.897404499999999],
            [49.9690376, 7.895451],
            [49.9690376, 7.895451],
            [49.9688003, 7.891565000000001],
            [49.9688003, 7.891565000000001],
            [49.966386, 7.888530899999999],
            [49.966386, 7.888530899999999],
            [49.9651325, 7.8884534],
            [49.9651325, 7.8884534],
            [49.9411728, 7.912222499999999],
            [49.9411728, 7.912222499999999],
            [49.9391022, 7.9152532],
            [49.9391022, 7.9152532],
            [49.9337381, 7.9157891],
            [49.9337381, 7.9157891],
            [49.9241653, 7.829844099999999],
            [49.9241653, 7.829844099999999],
            [49.9259564, 7.8275102],
            [49.9259564, 7.8275102],
            [49.922877, 7.8259417],
            [49.922877, 7.8259417],
            [49.92355939999999, 7.8055037],
            [49.92355939999999, 7.8055037],
            [49.9258713, 7.8004553],
            [49.9258713, 7.8004553],
            [49.9262293, 7.7978919],
            [49.9262293, 7.7978919],
            [49.92596469999999, 7.795387600000001],
            [49.92596469999999, 7.795387600000001],
            [49.9216437, 7.7577913],
            [49.9216437, 7.7577913],
            [49.91755209999999, 7.7473702],
            [49.91755209999999, 7.7473702],
            [49.9107566, 7.726173299999999],
            [49.9107566, 7.726173299999999],
            [49.9115306, 7.725327200000001]
        ]
    },
    "taxiid": 551,
    "riderequestid": 7
}, {
    "idtaxiroute": "4",
    "routingpath": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [49.9670749, 7.8994591],
            [49.9670378, 7.899477099999999],
            [49.9670378, 7.899477099999999],
            [49.9651449, 7.898171800000001],
            [49.9651449, 7.898171800000001],
            [49.9645179, 7.894035400000001],
            [49.9645179, 7.894035400000001],
            [49.9605222, 7.893961699999999],
            [49.9605222, 7.893961699999999],
            [49.95326799999999, 7.902490999999999],
            [49.95326799999999, 7.902490999999999],
            [49.9518747, 7.9065943],
            [49.9518747, 7.9065943],
            [49.9495675, 7.907795699999999],
            [49.9495675, 7.907795699999999],
            [49.9479066, 7.9125997],
            [49.9479066, 7.9125997],
            [49.9405005, 7.910934200000001],
            [49.9405005, 7.910934200000001],
            [49.9400513, 7.9114172]
        ]
    },
    "taxiid": 551,
    "riderequestid": 7
}]
```

Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < JSONOBJECT[i].routingpath.length; i++)
   {
       console.log("Type: " + JSONOBJECT[i].routingpath.coordinates[i][i]); 
    console.log("Types: " + i); 
   }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what is your exact requirement...?

Comment: I want to a loop with the coordinates and draw a polyline in openlayers and for this i need the length of the coordinates to have a length for the loop

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to use `JSONOBJECT[i]` in the calculation of the limit of the `for` loop that uses `i`.

You need nested loops, one for the `JSONOBJECT` array, and an inner one for `coordinates`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < JSONOBJECT.length; i++) {
    var coords = JSONOBJECT[i].routingpath.coordinates;
    for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
        console.log("Type: " + coords[j]);
    }
}
```